# Chart library for Angular with two Y axis

Tags: angularjs, charts

Is there any library for Angular where I can plot two Y axis on the same graph (one on the left and the other on the right for example)?
I tried libraries by [chinmaymk](https://github.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts) and [jtblin](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js), but haven't found suitable method.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var chartData = {
            "type":"mixed",
            "title":{
                "text":"Multiple Y Axis"
            },
            "scale-x":{
                
            },
            "scale-y":{
                "values":"0:50:5"
            },
            "scale-y-2":{
                "values":"0:40000:5000",
                "guide":{
                    "visible":false
                }
            },
            "series":[
                {
                    "values":[8,31,12,40,24,20,16,40,9],
                    "type":"bar",
                    "scales":"scale-x,scale-y",
                    "hover-state":{
                        "visible":false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "values":[11254,26145,17014,2444,17871,25658,34002,26178,20413],
                    "type":"line",
                    "scales":"scale-x,scale-y-2"
                }
            ]
        };

zingchart.render({
  id: "chart",
  data: chartData,
  width: "100%"
 });
```

```css
#chart {
  width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

[ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com) supports multiple y-axes with the `scale-y-n` objects. There's also an easy to use [Angular directive](https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-AngularJS) on Github.

There's a simple demo in the snippet and [here's a more real world example](http://www.zingchart.com/playground/run/537b6f0675008). You can right click the chart itself and select "View Source" to check out the JSON.

If you have any questions about implementation feel free to reach out - I'm on the ZC team.

Comment: can you please see my question maybe you have an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256487/i-want-to-change-the-chart-for-each-city-or-subcity-selected

Answer (score 1):

I've found [n3-charts](http://n3-charts.github.io/line-chart/) library that solves my problem.